# How to make multiplication operator (*) behave as short-circuit?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, short-circuiting

I have lots of computations, specially multiplication, where first part is sometimes zero and I don't want to evaluate second operand in that case. There are at least two short-circuit operators in C#: `&&` and `||` which evaluate second operand only if necessary. I want to achieve similar behavior with multiplication operator.

In **.net** you can't overload `&&` operator directly, but you can overload `&` and `false` operators, so you can use your extension points to change behavior of short-circuit operator. You can find more details at this article [C# operator overloading: the ‘&&’ operator](http://blog.onderweg.eu/2010/11/csharp-overloading-short-circuit-operators/)

**Is there any means to achieve this or *similar* behavior for multiplication operator?**

This is a pure syntax question, because implementation is very simple. Next method achieves exactly what I want in terms of functionality:

```
public static double ShortCircuitMultiply(double val, Func<double> anotherValue)
{
    var epsilon = 0.00000001;
    return Math.Abs(val) < epsilon ? 0 : val * anotherValue();
}
```

Note: this implementation is not full: in **C#** if you multiply `0.0` with 
  `Double.NaN`  or `Double.NegativeInfinity` or `Double.PositiveInfinity`, you'll get `NaN`, but in terms of `ShortCircuitMultiply` - only zero. Let's ignore this detail and it's really irrelevant in my domain.

So now if I call it as `ShortCircuitMultiply(0.0, longOperation)` where `longOperation` is `Func<double>`, last term won't be evaluated and result of an operation will be effectively zero.

The problem is, as I already stated, I would have lots of `ShortCircuitMultiply` calls and I want to make code more readable. I want code to be similar to `0.0 * longOperation()` if that is possible.

---

Another note: I've tried to build wrapper on `double` and create implicit casting to double and also overload `*` operator. I understand, that this is probably redundant: I wanted to acheive readability, but trying to build [yet another wrapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Anyway, next code  demonstrates my intent:

```
class MyDouble
{
    double value;
    public MyDouble(double value)
    {
        this.value = value; 
    }

    public static MyDouble operator *(MyDouble left, MyDouble right) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("* operator call");
        return new MyDouble(left.value * right.value);
    }

    public static implicit operator double(MyDouble myDouble)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("cast to double");
        return myDouble.value;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyDouble(double value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("cast to MyDouble");
        return new MyDouble(value);
    }
}
```

Now if I go with:

```
MyDouble zero = 0;

Console.WriteLine (zero * longOperation()); //longOperation is still Func<double>
```

I've receive:

```
cast to MyDouble            
called longOperation        <-- want to avoid this (it's printed from longOperation body)
cast to double             
cast to MyDouble
* operator call
cast to double   
0
```

But as you can see, `longOperation` is evaluated long before overloaded operator is called, and I can't substitute one of the parameters with `Func` or `Expression` to make it lazy.

Comment: I suspect the answer here is "no, you can't do that - unless you manually write the short-circuit check at the top of your custom operators... a short-ish circuit"

Comment: @MarcGravell by *custom operators* you mean overloading * or `ShortCircuitMultiply` ? I will probably stay with `ShortCircuitMultiply` implementation, just wanted to know if I'm missing something critical

Comment: You can't avoid calling `longOperation()` - for all the compiler knows that could have side-effects, and simply, `*` is *not designed* to be short-circuiting - it is *intended* to always evaluate both operands

Comment: Why not just use the `&` operator for multiplication?

Comment: @poke: Yes `&` would be normal multiplication and `&&` would be short-circuiting.

Comment: @poke: what dont you get? "you can't overload && operator directly, but you can overload & and false operators" to achieve that behavior.

Comment: @leppie Ah, that’s what you were referring to. Sorry, that wasn’t obvious.

Comment: I suppose there's no equivalent to C++'s expression templates in C#?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem with your `MyDouble` wrapper class is that you use it by calling `longOperation` directly. As `*` is not short circuiting, it will be called directly.

Instead, you could just make your wrapper accept a `Func<double>` as the second parameter instead of the double value itself. So it would work like the `ShortCircuitMultiply` function:

```
public static MyDouble operator *(MyDouble left, Func<double> right)
{
    return Math.Abs(left.value) < epsilon ? new MyDouble(0) : new MyDouble(left.value * right());
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
MyDouble x = 0;
Console.WriteLine(x * LongOperation);
```

And even chaining works:

```
MyDouble x = 5;
Console.WriteLine(x * OperationReturingZero * LongOperation);
```

#### Full example

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyDouble x = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(x * LongOperation);

        MyDouble y = 5;
        Console.WriteLine(y * OperationReturningZero * LongOperation);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static double LongOperation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LongOperation");
        return 5;
    }

    private static double OperationReturningZero()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OperationReturningZero");
        return 0;
    }
}

class MyDouble
{
    private static double epsilon = 0.00000001;
    private double value;

    public MyDouble(double value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static MyDouble operator *(MyDouble left, Func<double> right)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("* (MyDouble, Func<double>)");
        return Math.Abs(left.value) < epsilon ? new MyDouble(0) : new MyDouble(left.value * right());
    }

    public static MyDouble operator *(MyDouble left, MyDouble right)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("* (MyDouble, MyDouble)");
        return new MyDouble(left.value * right.value);
    }

    public static implicit operator double(MyDouble myDouble)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("cast to double");
        return myDouble.value;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyDouble(double value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("cast to MyDouble");
        return new MyDouble(value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
cast to MyDouble
* (MyDouble, Func<double>)
cast to double
0
cast to MyDouble
* (MyDouble, Func<double>)
OperationReturningZero
* (MyDouble, Func<double>)
cast to double
0
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, make an `operator *` (overload of `*`) whose right operand is a delegate. Of course it's just the `ShortCircuitMultiply` method he already has in another disguise, but it allows the infix syntax `a * MethodToGetB` or `a * (() => heavyExpression)`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to stick with `MyDouble operator *(MyDouble left, Func<double> right)` solution for now. Hope `MyDouble` won't add friction to development with doubles

Answer (score 13):

There is no way to easily do what you want. The C# language is a very "eager" language in that it always evaluates operands before it runs operators, even when as you note, you could possibly skip one by knowing the other. The only exceptions are `? :`, and its equivalents, `&&`, `||` and `??`. (All of which can be reduced to `? :`.)

As you correctly note, you can attain laziness through use of a lambda; a `Func<T>` represents a `T` that will be computed on demand. But as you also correctly note, the syntax for doing so is rather heavyweight.

Consider writing your program in Haskell if you must have lazy arithmetic. It's very lazy, and I gather it is very easy to define your own operator semantics. F# is also an option and is probably easier to learn for the C# programmer.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I appreciate your answer. I will stick for now with poke's alternative. By the way, now I'm already learning F# and plan to implement the same functionality there (some machine learning stuff). It would be very interesting to compare source code of both.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think "lambda lifting" means something different than what you used it for.

Comment: @Pubby: You're right, I was not using that term quite correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Well you could write an extension method for double, but I'm not sure if it's really what you're looking for.

You could then have code like this:

```
double z = someNumberThatMightBeZero();
double r = z.Times(number);
```

where `number` is a method returning a double.

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double z = zero();
            double r = z.Times(number);
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        }

        static double zero()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        static double number()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("in number()");
            return 100;
        }
    }

    public static class DoubleExt
    {
        public static double Times(this double val, Func<double> anotherValue)
        {
            const double epsilon = 0.00000001;
            return Math.Abs(val) < epsilon ? 0 : val * anotherValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good note, I've forgot to bring extension methods into place. It's definitely better that simple static method `ShortCircuitMultiply`, but not quite  `z * number`

Comment: Yep, but I don't think it's possible to reach that ideal! :)

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can see is something like this:

```
  struct LazyDouble {
    Func<double> Func;

    public LazyDouble(Func<double> func) : this() { Func = func; }

    public static implicit operator LazyDouble (double value) { 
      return new LazyDouble(()=>value); 
    }

    public static LazyDouble operator * (LazyDouble lhs, LazyDouble rhs) {
      var lhsValue = lhs.Func();
      if ( lhsValue == 0)
        return 0;
      else 
        return new LazyDouble(() => lhsValue * rhs.Func());
    }
    // other operators as necessary
  }
```

Comment: Dividing by zero is not defined.

Comment: Yet accountants regularly use expressions like `a / (a + b)` that are to display as 0, and propagate as 0,  on their worksheets. The use of debits and credits allows one to know that a and b are both positive, and so the denominator == 0 implies that the numerator also == 0. In this circumstance, it is **correct** to define division by 0 as being equal to 0.

Comment: If a and b are both positive (`> 0`), then `a + b` cannot be zero. And if you want to short-circuit to zero because you know that the dividend (`a`) is zero, then just check that one instead of suddenly definining an [undefined operation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26445/division-by-0).

Comment: Also, you are evalutating the function twice in each of the operators. That seems to be a terrible idea when `LongOperation` is indeed a *long* operation; or if it might have some additional side effects.

Comment: @poke: Thank you; see update. Debits and credits are _positive or zero_ (except in specific situations of some systems when they can be negative only for very specific transactions, that exactly cancel another already existing transaction).